# statistics and financial ratios

Tags: matrices, statistics, finance

Currently i am trying to derive the volatility of a financial ratio. I have calculated the volatility (standard deviation) of both the denominator and numerator however I am running into trouble whenever trying to derive the standard deviation of the ratio.

Initially I tried normally distributing each financial number (denominator & numerator, 10,000 z-scores), divide them at each individual z-score and take the standard deviation of the derived 10,000 ratios. However i found this to be understating the true standard deviation.

Then I tried to do the inverse; take the maximum of one ratio and the minimum of another ratio and the opposite to come up with the worst possible range. However I found this to be overstating the true standard deviation.

Any help would be incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution) should be helpful. Note that the ratio of two *standard* normal variable is Cauchy, with $\sigma = \infty$ so ratios can be much less well behaved than either the numerator or denominator. For your problem, see this [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v16/i04/paper), which discussed ratios of non-standard normals.